# Dataframe loses its contents after writing to database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-databricks

We had working code as below.

```py
print(f"{file_name} Before insert count", datetime.datetime.now(), scan_df_new.count())

scan_df_new.show()
```

```
scan_20220908120005_10 Before insert count 2022-09-14 11:37:15.853588 3
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
|            tran_id|t_store_id|      scan_datetime|         customer_id|updated_by|
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
|1230000000000000004|      4395|2022-09-08 03:00:01|20220816a51cee4264f1|Databricks|
|1230000000000000005|      4394|2022-09-08 02:58:00|20220816a51cee4264f1|Databricks|
|1230000000000000006|      4393|2022-09-08 03:00:04|20220816a51cee4264f1|Databricks|
+-------------------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

The data frame after the write operation is used for further business logic processing. This was working earlier. But recently we are observing a strange behavior, where in the data in the data frame is getting lost . When wee check the contents, or even the dataframe count its shows empty.

```py
scan_df_new.write.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbcUrl).option("dbtable", scan_table).mode("append").save()

print(f"{file_name} After insert count", datetime.datetime.now(), scan_df_new.count())

scan_df_new.show()
```

```
None

scan_20220908120005_10 After insert count 2022-09-14 11:37:18.372147 0

+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|tran_id|t_store_id|scan_datetime|customer_id|updated_by|
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Anything recently changed in the Databricks, which is impacting this?

Comment: Have you recently changed the spark/pyspark/hadoop version?
In your actual program, does anything happen after writing the dataframe to db? 

My guess is, that the data source is changed after the write operation. You did not add a cache or persist call, therefore I assume, that you also don´t have it in your actual program? scan_df_new will the be recalculated for all actions after the write operation (count, columns, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to add, this is on aws databricks. So we don't control much of the software stack.  As per my understanding the dataframe supposed to be carrying the data on the local memory. I am not sure whether any change in the source would impact the dataframe.  I didn't get, "You also don't have it in your actual  program".

Comment: the thing missing is how `scan_df_new` is calculated.
If `scan_df_new` is based on the DB then when you insert its content into the db and run `scan_df_new.show()` it goes to the DB which was altered so different results may arrive.
As @FelixKleineBösing mentioned, a cache or persist will fixate the dataframe.